# Encrypting a password to post to PHP - Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

Aloha! I'm wondering if there's any decent way to do a good form of encryption on Android without writing my own function to do one.

Are there any libraries I should be using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use AES, DES and 3DES, they all are included in java. I have posted a easy program from here http://sanjaal.com/java/186/java-encryption/tutorial-java-des-encryption-and-decryption/ which is using DES to encrypt/Decrypt

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

 class DESEncryption {

    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
    public static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES";
    private KeySpec myKeySpec;
    private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] keyAsBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;

    public DESEncryption() throws Exception
    {
        myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey";
        myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
        mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
    }

    /**
     * Method To Encrypt The String
     */
    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    /**
     * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
     */
    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText=null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }


    private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; bytes.length; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Testing the DES Encryption And Decryption Technique
     */
    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {
        DESEncryption myEncryptor= new DESEncryption();

        String stringToEncrypt="Sanjaal.com";
        String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt(stringToEncrypt);
        String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Value :" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Value :"+decrypted);

    }  

}
```

Comment: It took a little messing around to get the encrypt function to work on Android but I got it working. 

Thanks a lot! If anyone else finds this, here's an androidified version: 

http://pastebin.com/aByHyd7x

Comment: 1. Your code has some html artifacts. Please remove those. 2. You shouldn't recommend that people use DES. Use AES or 3DES or Blowfish. DES is easily brute-forceable. 3. You need to have ciphertext integrity, so an HMAC should be added or even easier an authenticated mode like GCM. 4. Always use a fully qualified Cipher string like "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" (also @Boncey)

Comment: I'll look into AES encryption. I was planning to do that anyway, but I'm only testing for now. Thanks for the advice :)